# 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'cell'? I need help exporting a list of data into another excel file

Tags: excel, pycharm, openpyxl, attributeerror, data-processing

I am trying to export a column of data into an excel sheet. My code works until line 28 (the d3rd for statement) where I receive an error message: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'cell'.

```
filename = '/home/elinor/Documents/data.xlsx'
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
filename1 = '/home/elinor/Documents/Report.xlsx'
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

for i in range (2, mr + 1):
    rowSelected = []
    for j in range (1, 1 + 1, 1):
        c = ws1.cell(row=i, column=j)
        rowSelected.append(c.value)
        print(rowSelected)
    for i in range(2, mr + 1, 1):
        countRow = 0
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(1, 1 + 1, 1):
            wb2.cell(row=i, column=j).value = c.value
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1
```

It Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elinor/scratch_1.py", line 28, in <module>
    wb2.cell(row=i, column=j).value = c.value
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'cell'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: A workbook doesn't have a cell. A worksheet does.

Comment: Excel doesn't have a `Cell` object - Word does. Excel has a `Cells` collection which is the collection of all the cells in a range. The biggest range there is is one that comprises an entire worksheet. All the worksheets in a workbook can't be combined into a single range. Therefore there is no Wb.Cells collection. Define a cell from the collection by its index or its coordinates. Ws.Cells(1) specifies the first cell in the collection. Ws.Cells(1, 1) specifies the cell at the intersection between first row and first column of the specified range (here Ws).